# Laravel5: Where do I place a css file with only backend design classes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a separate stylesheet (backend.css) for my admin backend css classes. Since clearly it shouldn't be in the public folder, where would be the appropriate location to store it?

Also, since HTML helper function:

```
{{ Html::style('css/stylesheet.css') }}
```

locates to only files in the public folder, how do I access it?

Comment: Why is the public folder not an appropriate place to put it? It is only a CSS file.

Comment: if u not want to put your css in public folder...suppose u put ur css file in mainproject/resources/assets/css/backend.css ...now u want to call it from mainproject/resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php like this way  {!!Html::style('resources/assets/css/backend.css')!!} or   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('resources/assets/css/backend.css')}}" />

Comment: Make a directory in `public/css/admin` and keep all the backend related css over there so that you can easily identify them.

Comment: @Borna No, I checked it and it seems it rather looks for 'resources' folder in the public folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "public" folder is called that way because it is accessible via HTTP. It does not refer to any specific part of your application (public or admin). So the "public" folder is the appropriate place for any files that have to be accessed directly via HTTP, like images, css and javascript files.